# What's the easiest way to add arrow for Android Button

Tags: android, android-button

I need to add Arrow to Next Button like that

[image]

What's the easiest way to achieve that? Making custom Compound view sounds like overkill

PS Symbol `>` is not nice.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    />
```

TextViews have support for compound drawables, where you can specify a drawable you want to be displayed next to the text. It can be above, below, right, left, start, end.

Notice also that I set the TextView to be clickable and focusable and that I gave it Android's default ripple background (where it shows the ripple effect when pressed).

EDIT

If you need the arrow to be directly after the text, you have to use a container and child Views:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/next" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You'll want to set your click listener on the LinearLayout.

Alternatively, use the U+276fa character as part of your TextView's text: `❯`. It's not `>` and looks more like an arrow.

Comment: There is one problem with it. If my button  `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, the icon will be at the right edge, not next to the label.

Comment: Then you need to make your own layout. I'll edit with an example.

Comment: as I mentioned in the topic I wanted to avoid creating Compound Views, but thanks to you I know that's probably not possible. BTW The unicode is too small

Comment: Try U+276f instead.

Comment: The baseline isn't aligned this time. Thank you anyway, I will stick to Custom View

Answer (score 1):

Try this custom button, it calculates where to put the icon directly next to the text.

```
public class CenteredIconButton extends Button {
private static final int LEFT = 0, TOP = 1, RIGHT = 2, BOTTOM = 3;

private Rect textBounds = new Rect();
private Rect drawableBounds = new Rect();

public CenteredIconButton(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CenteredIconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.buttonStyle);
}

public CenteredIconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    if (!changed) return;

    final CharSequence text = getText();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text.toString(), 0, text.length(), textBounds);
    } else {
        textBounds.setEmpty();
    }

    final int width = getWidth() - (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
    final int height = getHeight() - (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());

    final Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();

    if (drawables[LEFT] != null) {
        drawables[LEFT].copyBounds(drawableBounds);
        int leftOffset =
                (width - (textBounds.width() + drawableBounds.width()) + getRightPaddingOffset()) / 2 - getCompoundDrawablePadding();
        drawableBounds.offset(leftOffset, 0);
        drawables[LEFT].setBounds(drawableBounds);
    }

    if (drawables[RIGHT] != null) {
        drawables[RIGHT].copyBounds(drawableBounds);
        int rightOffset =
                ((textBounds.width() + drawableBounds.width()) - width + getLeftPaddingOffset()) / 2 + getCompoundDrawablePadding();
        drawableBounds.offset(rightOffset, 0);
        drawables[RIGHT].setBounds(drawableBounds);
    }

    if (drawables[TOP] != null) {
        drawables[TOP].copyBounds(drawableBounds);
        int topOffset =
                (height - (textBounds.height() + drawableBounds.height()) + getBottomPaddingOffset()) / 2 - getCompoundDrawablePadding();
        drawableBounds.offset(topOffset, 0);
        drawables[TOP].setBounds(drawableBounds);
    }
}
```

}